# Will reducing retention period in AWS SQS boost the performance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have an application that has a Consumer and a Producer.

The Producer will push the messages to the SQS.

The Consumer is reading from the queue but reading the last message is taking too much time.

I have set the retention period to be **4 days** and also reading the messages in lesser batch size.

I am not deleting the messages from the SQS for 4 days so for over the period of time these messages are getting accumulated. Does this impact the performance of the SQS?

If I reduce the retention period to a lower time will it increase the performance of the SQS queue?

Answer (score 2):

Reducing retention time will not improve the performance of SQS, the only thing what retention time does is keep your messages in the queue for the specified duration until it is consumed, if it is not consumed then it will delete that message after the given threshold. So reducing retention time will not have any impact on the performance unless your queue is struggling with memory issues.

Some of the tips to increase performance of your SQS -

1. Use batching while reading and writing messages.
2. Keep message size as small as possible and consider using serialization formats like JSON.
3. Use services like AWS Lambda to read messages from SQS because it can scale effectively, maybe the processes that you are using to consume the messages are busy and not scaling effectively.
4. Review SQS limits and create monitoring dashboards.